# PERL: Using regex to subtract columns

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file like this:

```
3107  0.9  0.0   0.0 chr1 29312346 29312694 (219937927) C L1HS LINE/L1  (4)  6151 5803  54360
8095  0.5  0.0   0.0 chr1 31040661 31041597 (218209024) + L1HS LINE/L1  5203 6139 (16)  57249
...
```

When the 9th column is `C`, I need to subtract column 14 from 13, and when the 9th column is `+`, I need to subtract column 12 from 13.

I understand I can create arrays, but how can I use a regex, such as `($line =~/(\w+)\s+(\w+)/)`, to solve this instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wanted to use a regex, here is another solution. It is perhaps a bit unsharp, because you did not define your lines cleanly but with only two example lines, and for those, it works. I commented the regex so that you can see, which part of the expression is matching a certain group and which of them are captured.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

while( <DATA> )
{
    if( $_ =~ /[0-9]+           # 1
                    \s+
               [0-9.]+          # 2
                    \s+
               [0-9.]+          # 3
                    \s+
               [0-9.]+          # 4
                    \s+
               [a-z0-9]+        # 5
                    \s+
               [0-9]+           # 6
                    \s+
               [0-9]+           # 7
                    \s+
               \([a-z0-9]+\)    # 8
                    \s+
               ([c+])           # 9 -> capture group 1
                    \s+
               [a-z0-9]+        # 10
                    \s+
               [a-z0-9\/]+      # 11
                    \s+
               \(?([0-9]+)\)?   # 12 -> capture group 2
                    \s+
               ([0-9]+)         # 13 -> capture group 3
                    \s+
               \(?([0-9]+)\)?   # 14 -> capture group 4
                    \s+
               [0-9]+?          # 15
            /ix )
    {
        say "Matched: $_";
        say "Operation: $1";

        if( $1 eq "+" )
        {
            say "$2 - $3 = ".( $2 - $3 );
        }
        elsif( $1 eq "C" )
        {
            say "$4 - $3 = ".( $4 - $3 );
        }
        else
        {
            say "Nothing do to here...";
        }
    }
}

exit;
#1     2   3     4   5    6        7        8           9 10   11       12   13   14    15
__DATA__
3107  0.9  0.0   0.0 chr1 29312346 29312694 (219937927) C L1HS LINE/L1  (4)  6151 5803  54360
8095  0.5  0.0   0.0 chr1 31040661 31041597 (218209024) + L1HS LINE/L1  5203 6139 (16)  57249
```

Update:

As you can see in the [perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), I used the `x` flag to have comments in my regex. The `i` flag makes it case insensitive.

Furthermore, I didn't just try to devide all the single columns by whitespaces but also by their types, which is an advantage of using a regular expression. While `\s+` expressions are seperators for columns here, allowing arbitary amounts of whitespace all the single groups are kind of specified. That allows to find non-conforming lines. For example, by defining caputre group `$1` as `([c+])` I was able to reduce the possible characters, that trigger an operation to `C` and `+` ( and `c` because of case-inesensitivity).

Binding a group to a variable (capturing it) is done by using parenthises.
 This way, I was able to only pick the columns I really need (see the comments).

Answer (score 2):

You can split at white spaces into `@F` array(first value being `$F[0]`), subtract columns, and output values separated by space.

```
perl -lane'
  $F[12] -= $F[13] if $F[8] eq "C";
  $F[12] -= $F[11] if $F[8] eq "+";
  print "@F";
' file
```

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a regex for a problem like this.

If you're just working with columns separated by whitespace, the proper tool is [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

```
my @cols = split ' ', $line;
```